# Autodesk Forge import IFC failed

Tags: autodesk-forge, ifc

our customer try to show IFC model through method https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/bucket_name/objects/model_name. IFC model is huge, about 100km, it is road design. He can't show it in Forge, he got error that model is empty, although it has 120MB. Model is in IFC4. Has You any documentation to supported IFC classes, or model size to show in FOrge ? He try to divide model to smaller parts, but nothing happen.

Milan Nemec, Graitec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check:

- Did you call the conversion job to translate the IFCs to SVF first? Using this endpoint [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/)?
- Is the conversion completed? Try [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) to query the progress.
- And if everything works out the manifest response should contain SVF derivatives similar to:

```
{
  "type": "manifest",
  "hasThumbnail": "true",
  "status": "success",
  "progress": "complete",
  "region": "US",
```

**EDIT**

- For IFC models exported from Revit try switch to the IFC loader by specifying in your job payload:

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c2JzYjIzMzMvc2JiLmlmYw"
    },
    "output": {
        "formats": [
        {
            "type": "svf",
            "views": ["3d", "2d"], "advanced": {
                "switchLoader": true
              }
        }]
```

Comment: Request pass successfully, but in result is note "There is no geometry that can be displayed"

I send You in email access to IFC file.